# How to create 3D polygon layer in QGIS 3 or convert 2D layer to 3D similar to PostGIS function ST_Force3d()

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

Right now I'm creating a polygon layer like this:

```
self.poly = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "target_polygons", "memory")
```

Is there something I need to do to make this 3D? Alternatively I can just convert to 3D before saving this to file, is there an easy way to do that?

The z value can be all zeros, just need XYZ instead of XY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to solve this by using this code when saving to file:

```
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(inputlayer, str(outputlayer), "utf-8", QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:4326"), "KML", 
                                            overrideGeometryType = QgsWkbTypes.PolygonZ, includeZ = True)
```